# Random number upper limit and lower limit

Tags: javascript, random

I'm working on a random number guessing game in JavaScript. I want the user to input a lowLimit and a highLimit and have the random number generated between those two numbers. I tried hardcoding the lowLimit and highLimit as below:

```
let lowLimit = 5;
let highLimit = 20;
let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * highLimit);


  if (random < lowLimit) {
    random += lowLimit;
  }
console.log(random);
```

and everything works well.

However, when I allow the user to input values, the random number always becomes the sum of lowLimit and upperLimit. I cannot figure this out!

My final code is this:

```
let lowLimit = prompt('Input the lower limit:');
let highLimit = prompt('Input the upper limit:');
let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * highLimit);
let tries = 0;

  if (random < lowLimit) {
    random += lowLimit;
  }

  console.log(random);

let guess = prompt('Secret number generated. Enter guess:');

while (guess !== random) {
  if (guess === 'q') break;
  tries += 1;
  if (guess > random) {
    prompt('You guessed too high. Guess again...');
  } else if (guess < random) {
    prompt('You guessed too low. Guess again...');
  } else {
    alert('You guessed correctly! You made ' + tries + " guesses.");
  }
}
```

Comment: Not what you asked, but you shouldn't do it this way anyway, because this will be more likely to generate some values than other. Eg if lower limit is 5 and upper is 20, you'll be far more likely to get numbers between 5 and 10 than between 10 and 20. Use `Math.floor(Math.random() * (highLimit - lowLimit)) + lowLimit`

Comment: as for your actual question, it's probably because `prompt` returns a string, even if a numeric string was entered. Try using the `Number` function to convert those to actual numbers before doing comparisons.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I did notice that. That makes perfect sense, since most of the values will end up falling between 5 and 10 because of the bump up from lowLimit with numbers lower than lowLimit. Thanks!

OH! That's why. Because it's concatenating the string values that are input. Much appreciated!

Comment: Why would you not use parseInt() to convert the user input?

Comment: you could if you wanted. There are actually 3 ways, `parseInt`, `Number` and the `+` operator. Of these, the last 2 are equivalent and directly coerce to a number. `parseInt` is more tricky and, without going into detail, has slightly different behaviour and some annoying additional features - none of which you need to worry about here but which always make me wary of it. There are plenty who will suggest you use it though - as I said, it doesn't matter here, and in most cases where you want to convert a numberic string to a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few tweaks to improve the code, and one bug fix (the case where user guesses correctly on the first try, they will receive no feedback)...

```js
// + is concise way to coerce an int
const lowLimit = +prompt('Input the lower limit:');
const highLimit = +prompt('Input the upper limit:');
// note - we could add checks here for invalid or disordered values

// this presumes we want random to be exclusive of highLimit. if not, we'll need to tweak
const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (highLimit - lowLimit) + lowLimit);

// we'll vary the prompt during the game
let promptMsg = 'Enter guess:', guesses = 0, guess;

// bug fix and cleanup: do while, so we always play at least once
// prompt in just one place, alter the prompt message to represent game state
do {
  guess = prompt(promptMsg);
  guesses++;
  if (guess !== 'q') {
    guess = +guess;
    if (guess > random) {
      promptMsg = 'You guessed too high. Guess again...';
    } else if (guess < random) {
      promptMsg = 'You guessed too low. Guess again...';
    } 
  }
} while (guess !== 'q' && guess !== random);

const endMsg = guess === 'q' ? 'Ok. Quitting' : 'You guessed correctly.'
const guessesMsg = `You made ${guesses} ${guesses === 1 ? 'guess' : 'guesses'}`;
alert(`${endMsg} ${guessesMsg}`)
```

Comment: I wasn't aware that a do...while was available in JavaScript! That wasn't presented in Colt Steele's Web Developer Bootcamp 2022, where I am learning on Udemy. I have seen do...while in other languages and knew about it's benefit of running at least once, I'm glad I know now I can use it! The tertiary operator was also not introduced =( This was very helpful, thank you!

Comment: Glad to help.  Also note the string interpolation: `\`this is text ${this_is_any_js_expr}\``

Answer (score 1):

This solution works. Any refactoring suggestions are welcome.

```
let lowLimit = Number(prompt('Input the lower limit:'));
let highLimit = Number(prompt('Input the upper limit:'));
while (!lowLimit || !highLimit) {
  lowLimit = Number(prompt('Input a valid lower limit:'));
  highLimit = Number(prompt('Input a valid upper limit:'));
}
lowLimit = Number(lowLimit);
highLimit = Number(highLimit);
let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (highLimit - lowLimit) + lowLimit);

let guesses = 0;

  console.log(random);


  guess = prompt('Enter guess:');
while (guess !== random) {
  
  if (guess === 'q') {
    alert('Ok. Quitting... You made ' + guesses + ' guesses')
      break;
  }

  guesses += 1;
  guess = Number(guess);

  if (guess > random) {
    guess = prompt('You guessed too high. Guess again...');
  } else if (guess < random) {
    guess = prompt('You guessed too low. Guess again...');
  } else alert('You guessed correctly! You made ' + guesses + " guesses.");
  
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

We can generate a random number by using the Date.now()

`let res = Date.now() % (highLimit - lowLimit + 1) + lowLimit.`

This is because nobody can estimate the time in milisecond the code runs.